# Get value from JSON response Object

Tags: ios, arrays, json

I am making a JSON request and want to get an int value from one of the fields.

```
{
"currentPage": 1,
"numberOfPages": 5,
"totalResults": 234,
"data": [],
"status": "success"
}
```

I want to get the value of numberOfPages. My code is as follows

```
_pages = [responseObject objectForKey:@"numberOfPages"];
_numberOfPages = (int)_pages;
NSLog(@"%d", _numberOfPages);
```

Instead of the value for numberOfPages, the NSLog is 150198512. Can somebody please explain why? Trying object at index 0 causes it to crash.

Answer (score 2):

`_pages` should be an `NSNumber` in your definition. You can't cast that to get a primitive type, you have to request the primitive type. `_numberOfPages` should be an `NSInteger` (or perhaps `NSUInteger`) and you should get the value with:

```
_numberOfPages = [_pages integerValue];
```

Aside: consider using `self.pages` and `self.numberOfPages` rather than accessing the instance variables directly (it could help you with maintenance in the future).

Using `self.pages` results in a call to the `pages` (or `self.pages = xxx` in a call to `setPages:xxx`) method to get (or set) the content of the instance variable (`_pages`). So, if you have a custom implementation of that method it will be called and your custom logic will run. If you just use `_pages` then it won't be called and you will need to do a lot of editing later if you need to make a change.

Your best option is to use `self.XXX = xxx` whenever you want to update a property and `XXX xxx = self.xxx` when you want to use it.

This isn't a hard and fast rule. [Interesting discussion here](http://blog.bignerdranch.com/83-83/).

Comment: Thank you!. 

Could you explain what the difference betweek _varlable and self.variable is? Sorry I am new to Obj-C...